# Why in Chrome and Firefox different element width?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, haml, mozilla

I have `.sidebar` with `width: 25em; margin: 0; padding: 0;`. And on Chrome width = 169.6px, on Firefox width = 260px.

Why? How is the width in firefox considered?

Comment: What do you have in the sidebar?

Comment: Nothing! It's empty

Comment: Are you using `box-sizing: border-box`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"em" is a unit based on typography size.
The font size in different browsers might be different (by default), thus the X * < font size > will have a different outcome
Set a font-size for the web page and try again

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the default font size of Chrome and Firefox differs (assuming you're using default font sizes) - as em corresponds to x number of times the size of the current font.

Granted, based on 25em it is coming out with some odd figures for both - but try putting in a font-size and see if they still end up being different widths?